# ImageView in ListView with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-imageview

I am trying to create a custom `ListView` using an `ArrayAdapter`. POJO `Item` class:

```
public class Item {

    String itemTitle = "", itemTimestamp = "", itemDescription = "";
    ImageView itemImage;

    public String getTitle() {
        return itemTitle;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return itemTimestamp;
    }

    public ImageView getImage() {
        return itemImage;
    }

    public Item(String itemTitle, String itemTimestamp, String itemDescription,
            ImageView itemImage) {
        super();
        this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
        this.itemTimestamp = itemTimestamp;
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }

    public void setItemTitle(String title) {
        itemTitle = title;
    }

    public void setItemTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        itemTimestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public void setItemDescription(String itemDesc) {
        itemDescription = itemDesc;
    }

    public void setItemImage(ImageView image) {
        itemImage = image;
    }

}
```

And here how the custom array adapter looks like.It is shown as below:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<Item> items;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_default, null);
    }

    Item p = items.get(position);

    if (p != null) {

        TextView list_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        TextView list_description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_description);
        TextView list_timestamp = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.list_timestamp);
        ImageView list_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        if (list_title != null) {
            list_title.setText(p.getTitle());
        }

        if (list_description != null) {
            list_description.setText(p.getDescription());
        }

        if (list_timestamp != null) {
            list_timestamp.setText(p.getTimeStamp());
        }

        if (list_image != null) {
            list_image.setImageResource(p.getImage(R.drawable.btn_bg_pressed));
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

}

Error:

```
The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView)
```

I am not sure how to set the default image for the `ListView` and that should change according the the array I feed it in at run time from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign as an image(picture) a `ImageView` object.
In your `Item` class instead of an `ImageView` you could store the `id`(like `R.drawable.some_name`) of the image for that particular item object as an `int`(like `R.drawable.btn_bg_presse`d) and then in your `getView()` method the assignment will be :

```
list_image.setImageResource(p.getImageId())
```

where the method getImageId()(from class Item) would be like this:

```
private int itemImageId;

public int getImageId() {
   return itemImageId;
}
```

Comment: the image has to change dynamically but show the default image from the local drawable folder till its loaded. could you plz show can i assign this image in the code ?

Comment: @HarshaMV i don't think i understand your problem. In your custom row layout `R.layout.list_item_default` you have an `ImageView`. Have you tried to set the attribute `src` to your `ImageView` like this: `android:src="@drawable/some_drawable"` so your ImageView already has a picture?

Comment: yeah i have done that to get a default image. now when i feed an Array the image view should show an image from a URL mentioned. i have 4 fields - 3 text view and 1 of them is the image view.